# Get last item added to cart

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce2, mysql

Does anyone know a nice way to get the last lineItem(s) added to a cart in craft commerce via twig template? Example use case, an 'added to cart' confirmation page. I know for this you could query param a product/variant id but multiple could be submitted.

I attempted `{cart.lineItems | last}` but they do not seem to be in date order. I also checked the class models but didn't find any helpful methods or attributes.

Perhaps some kind of db query, as sql has date fields?

Answer (score 2):

Since multiple line item can be updated or added to the cart at the same time, it would be hard to point to a specific line item that is newest.

The line items have a `dateUpdate` column you could sort and query on.

```
{% set result = craft.query()
    .select('*')
    .from('{{%commerce_lineitems}}')
    .where({
        'orderId': cart.id
    })
    .orderBy('dateUpdated ASC')
    .one()
%}
```

We could look to added a `lastUpdateLineItem()` method to the order element in future version of Craft Commerce. You can submit the idea here: https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues

Comment: Perfect, thanks Luke. And yes, I see how multiple lines could cause a problem, such as changing quantities etc, but as far as adding items to the cart, I expect the majority of sites add one item at a time (regardless of the qty).

Comment: I've tried this out and it seems that .orderBy('...ASC') and ('..DESC') return the first lineItem added I believe because the cart updates all line items together. I tried using dateCreated but this doesn't work if I go back to add additional items to a previously added lineItem

Comment: @lukeholder did `lastUpdateLineItem` ever get added to commerce? If not is this something you’d still consider adding?

Answer (score 1):

If your use-case is where you *do* only allow a single product at a time to be added to the cart, then one simple way I think you could do this is just take the first item in the `lineItems` array. I say this because *it seems* that whenever a product gets added to the cart, it becomes the first item in the array.

I can't find any documentation on this but I suspect this is how Commerce was designed as that would reflect most user's expectations that the most recent thing they add is typically shown first in a list of products in their cart.

Comment: Makes sense @Mike, but I have a feeling this may break with updated qty etc.. but I like the idea, and may well do the job!

Comment: Actually, I don't think it does break with a quantity update... though I haven't tested thoroughly it seems the order of item does not change.

Comment: @mike I’m trying to do the same thing to get the last added item. What was you final approach/solution?